# ActiveRecord RecordNotFound localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am trying to localize my rails application (webservice).
I installed the gem 'rails-i18n', which works fine.

Except that it does not translate ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound message.
In rails code:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb

```
raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{@klass.name} with #{conditions.to_a.collect {|p| p.join(' = ')}.join(', ')}"
```

It seems that the message is hard coded.

Is there any solution, apart not using the Model.find_by_'attribute' ?

Comment: NOTE: in rails4, find_by_'attribute_name'! is deprecated, so the occurrences of this error is greatly reduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sufficient for my reason to tell user more informative message:

```rb
exception.message.match /^Couldn't find (\w+) with (id=([\S]*))?/
msg = t 'activerecord.exceptions.not_found', klass: $1, id: $3
```

and since I wanted a czech transaltion:

```rb
cs:
  activerecord:
    exceptions:
      not_found: "Nelze nalézt %{klass} s id=%{id}"
```

..when is something hard coded the only way is to hard de-code it

Answer (score 2):

Another way in YAML config:

```
en:
 activerecord:
   exceptions:
     not_found: "%{model_name} not found"
```

You can also set a plural form for model names, adding as following:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: Dude
        other: Dudes
```

Comment: You can also set a plural form for model names, adding as following:

en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user:
        one: Dude
        other: Dudes

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the RecordNotFound exception in the application controller and return a localized message. This way you can also alter the default behavior for 404s:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found

  private

    def not_found
      render :json => { :message => I18n.t('exception.record_not_found') },
             :status => :not_found
    end

end
```

Comment: yes, but i will loose the contextuality of the original message which displays the klass and attribute name !

Comment: And what do you need this information for? IMHO for the user it's irrelevant what wasn't found, but only that something went wrong. If you want to log this kind of errors, you can specify that not_found takes an argument exception. So you can access it and log it or whatever...

Comment: Because it's a webservice, and clients must know what they are doing wrong without contacting our support.

Comment: You can recover the class name - even localized - with `controller_name.classify.constantize.model_name.human` and get things such as the ID from the `params` hash. [Ondrej's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20836667/2021397) will break as soon as the default message is revised.